# RMISecurityManager vs. SecurityManager

Tags: java, security, rmi

According to the [Java API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/RMISecurityManager.html),

> RMISecurityManager implements a policy that is no different than the policy implemented by SecurityManager. Therefore an RMI application should use the SecurityManager class or another application-specific SecurityManager implementation instead of this class.

If this is the case, then what is the point of having a separate RMISecurityManager class?  Are there any situations where it should be used over SecurityManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point. If you look at the definition of RMISecurityManager:

```
public class RMISecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

    /**
     * Constructs a new <code>RMISecurityManager</code>.
     * @since JDK1.1
     */
    public RMISecurityManager() {
    }
}
```

It really does **nothing**. My guess is that it exists for historical reasons. You never really gain anything by using it.

Comment: I guess the Java people planned to put more in for RMISecurityManager, but never did. :P  Thanks!